# How to set attr id and class in form widget

Tags: symfony

How can I set attr id and class in twig, something like :

```
{{ form_widget(form.description,{'attr':{'id':"editor-one",'class':"editor-wrapper"}}) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, wou want to add a class to a form. You can do so by passing the class as an attribute option to createFormBuilder.

```
$this->createFormBuilder($entity, array('attr' => array('class' => 'classname')));
```

I imagine you can do the same with ID, although I have not tried that myself.

Comment: Actually my problem is that when i use this code it doesn't give the same result as  :  <div id="editor-one" class="editor-wrapper"></div>

Answer (score 1):

You must move 'id' outside of 'attr', like this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.description,{'id':"editor-one", 'attr':{'class':"editor-wrapper"}}) }}
```

Comment: Actually my problem is that when i use this code it doesn't give the same result as  :  <div id="editor-one" class="editor-wrapper"></div>

Comment: Because the form_widget only render the input and label, if you need create a div, you can call form_widget inside, like this:

`<div id="editor-one" class="editor-wrapper">
{{ form_widget(form.description) }}
</div>`